# Canvas element with Spotify API

Tags: canvas, webkit, html5-canvas, spotify

I am currently playing (test developing) an application that can be run on Spotify software platform. On the official website for Spotify Developers, the description clearly says that:

> JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS3

are the languages may be used for developing applications for the Spotify. As well as after reading an essay of two students (*one of them works at Spotify*) at http://www.essays.se/essay/b72aaa236b/ I found that software uses WebKit for some of its tasks.

Now, I have one working application where I mostly use Canvas element (*HTML5*) to render graphics. So I wanted to test it on Spotify, but it seems that Spotify's WebKit does not allow the use of Canvas at all.

Why is it like that? Are there any security concerns or is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas should work just fine in Spotify Apps API — I've used it myself just fine. Choose "Show HTML5 Support" from the Develop menu and you'll see canvas right up there near the top.

Spotify uses the Chromium rendering engine, so anything supported by Spotify in the above list will work like it does in Chrome.

Comment: ok, i guess that was the problem. I have tested with latest Safari and now i see that my application doesn't work with Chrome. Thanks
P.S. going to refine code and find functions that do not work with Chrome